# Emacs org-mode: what is the meaning of this agenda decoration?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've puzzled over this quite a bit, searched the docs, and still can't find an answer, so here goes:  every so often I note that my agenda view's buffer name will get decorated with something like:

```
*Org Agenda(a:2013-10-31---2013-10-31) <-+
           ^--- this is the decoration --+
```

I don't know how this occurs -- I assume it's some inadvertent mode/filter/etc I am invoking when in the agenda view.  I can't dismiss/cancel it, short of restarting Emacs, when I then see the agenda view buffer name as I normally do:

```
*Org Agenda*
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use sticky agenda views, your agenda buffers become persistent.

As you can have many views open at the same time, Org needs a way to distinguish among them. It does this by suffixing the name of the buffer with the key (and eventually some parameters) which triggered that particular agenda view.

If you don't use the sticky agendas, you'll only get one agenda buffer open at any time, with the standard name "*Org Agenda*".

Comment: Thanks -- I believe I've been periodically inadvertently toggling sticky mode on with `*` in the agenda view while attempting to create a new section header in another buffer that didn't actually have focus yet.  Guess I need to read up on sticky agenda views :)